# MySQL master slave replication from first binlog position

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave

I have a couple of live databases that need migrating over to a new server. These are large databases constantly in use.

I want to setup replication with a slave on the new server and begin porting data across. However, I'd like to try and avoid doing a `mysqldump` on the current master data to get the initial binlog position as I don't want to lock down the database for an extended period of time.

Is there a way that I can find out the earliest `master_log_pos` so I can start replication from the very start? If not, are there any other solutions that avoid halting transactions (as much as possible)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think Percona's `Xtrabackup` is helpful for you.

`Xtrabackup` is hot backup tool which makes you can backup MySQL while it is running.

With `Xtrabackup` you can make data backup quickly even if data is large and move backups to slaves.

- [How to setup a slave for replication in 6 simple steps with Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html) is good start point.
- http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/ is Xtrabackup documentation
- [Setting up Master-Slave replication using xtrabackup](http://phpblogger.de/archives/296-Setting-up-Master-Slave-replication-using-xtrabackup.html) also describes how to use it for making slave.